# Substituting (*x).y with x->y

Tags: regular-expression, replace, macro

I am coding a C project and as I am unexperienced, everytime I needed to access the element of a pointer to a struct I typed `(*x).y` (where x is a struct and y an item), which I just realized could be rewritten as `->` which would look much nicer. So I first tried to make a regular expression to find all such occurences. I thought `/(/*.+/)/.` would work, but it gave some strange unwanted occurences. For example `(queue_t *queue)` would match which I don't understand why.

I'm also unsure what macro could be used if I got the correct regex. I thought making then a macro which deletes the first 2 characters, and then would go to the "end" to replace `).` with `->`, but then if I have something of the type `(*(*a).b)).c` I don't know how to find the correct `)`.

Also are there better alternatives to do what I want other than use regular expressions and macros?

Answer (score 5):

Iwould try it like this:

```
%s/(\*\(\k*\))\./\1->/gc
```

The search string is:

- `(` opening   parenthesis
- `\*` a literal `*`
- `\(...\)` a match group. This can later be addressed with `\1`

  - `\k*` any number of keywor characters
- `)` closing  parenthesis
- `\.` a literal `.`

The replace is:

- `\1` This is replaced with what is matched by the test within `\(...\)`
- `->`

See: `:help /\k`, `:help /\(` and `:help /\1`.